# How do I change the render order in the blender 2.8 2D animation tool

Tags: modifiers, 2d

I started experimenting with the 2D animation tool yesterday but while using the array modifier to make a crowd I had the problem that all objects that overlapped overlapped the exact opposite way you'd think they would. Somewhat fixed it by rotating the camera around 180° but the problem persists in the top left corner. There is a button to "Keep original stroke on top", but that only helps for the original row and I'd prefer to know how to do it right than working around problems.

I'm also sorry if I did anything wrong, I'm new here.

[image: As you can see people in the top left overlap weirdly, while everything else is fine.]